# Java: Thread.sleep() inside while loop not working

Tags: java, multithreading

Alright, I'm new to threading, so my question might be pretty dumb. But what I want to ask is, I have this class, let's say its name is MyClass.java. And then inside one of its methods is callThread(), which I want to print something out, sleep, and return control to MyClass.java's method. How do I do that?

Currently, my code goes something like this:

```
class MyClass {
    void method()
    {
        MyThread thread = new MyThread();
        thread.run();
        // do some other stuff here...
    }
}
```

And then, this will be the MyThread:

```
class MyThread implements Runnable {
    public void run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            System.out.println("hi");
            this.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

I was hoping that MyThread would print "hi", pass back control to MyClass, and then print "hi" again one second later. Instead, MyThread freezes up my entire program so having it in there doesn't work at all...

Is there any way around this?

Comment: thread.run() is a normal method invocation, you need to replace this as answered by Tomas

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be callig thread.start()

More on that in the manual: [Defining and Starting a Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html)

Comment: Thanks so much!! It works now! ;) Never knew start() and run() were completely different methods

Comment: yeah, thread.run will just cause it to call the method, however thread.start() actually tells the Java Virtual Machine to run the run() method, that way your main class will not have to wait for your infinite loop to get done with (which it never would)

Answer (score 4):

You must have to call start() method of Thread class.

```
MyThread thread = new MyThread();
Thread th=new Thread(thread);
th.start();
```

sleep() is an instance method of Thread class and MyThread class is not a thread (It's a runnable) so you need to use `Thread.currentThread().sleep()` method.

```
while (true)
 {
     System.out.println("hi");
     try{
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
     }catch(Exception ex){ }
  }
```

Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) tutorial for more info on thread.